# Difference between weak and strong formulation of a Cauchy problem solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

While studying the theory of differential equations (only ordinary equations in fact, I'm just getting started), the teacher told us about these two different kinds of formulation. Given a Cauchy problem, say $y(t)'=f(t,y(t))$ with $y(0)=y_0$, the strong formulation tells us that a solution is "strong" if it is $C^{1}$ and solves the Cauchy problem. The weak formulation instead states that a solution is "weak" if it is continuous and satisfies $y(t)=y_0 + \int_{0}^{t} f(\tau,y(\tau)) d \tau$. Then we prove that a solution is weak if and only if it is strong. But I don't understand why they bothered giving two different definitions of the exactly same thing. Why this? Isn't the second just a different writing of the Cauchy problem? I repeat, I'm only getting started, maybe this distinction makes more sense when you go deeper with the theory.

Comment: I can think of two reasons: 1.  The weak formulation leads in a natural way to an existence/uniqueness proof for solutions, which your teacher is probably going to discuss (cf. Picard iteration, Peano existence theorem).  2.  The weak formulation allows $f$, and consequently $y$, to be less regular.  For example, if $f(t,y)=t/|t|$ is not continuous, then the $C^1$ formulation makes no sense, but there is a unique $C^0$ solution $y$ to the weak Cauchy problem.

Comment: Yeah I had thought about the second one, but then again, in this case they are the same thing. When does the weak formulation happens to be more general? Maybe when working with differential equations with partial derivatives? (I don't know, I am just guessing randomly)

Comment: The solution would not be strong if I had used the better example $f(t,y)=(t-1)/|t-1|$; is that what you meant by "in this case they are the same thing"?

Comment: Ok I get it, the fact is that we only consider the case with $f$ continuous. In that case they are the same thing

Comment: Yes.  For partial differential equations, it's again the case that the weak formulation extends the strong formulation, although it looks a little different than the above.  There are also more general ODE weak formulations, but they all try to extend the strong formulation.